# Texlive 2019 installation issue

Tags: texlive, installing

I have an issue installing Texlive 2019 on windows 10.
After the initial parameters setting, the installation begin, but fail at the first package untar.
the last time I tried the `-gui text` parameter and I saw the following error message before the parameters request:

```
C:\Users\giuliano.favro\Desktop\LaTex\install\install-tl-20191210>install-tl-windows.bat -gui text
Loading http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
```

and this is the extract of log file

```
Installing [0001/3903, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: texlive.infra [392k]
TLUtils::untar: C:\Users\giuliano.favro\Desktop\LaTex\install\install-tl-20191210\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe xmf C:\Temp\j3VqjjrMK2\FICuSH6CZw/texlive.infra.tar failed (in C:/texlive/2019)
TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
```

I already tried to change mirrors or some installation parameters but the script fail any time trying to untar the `texlive.infra.tar` package.

Where is my fault?

thanks.

---

Update 1:

In the mean time I tried to monitor the temporary directory used by the installing script, since it's deleted at the and of any installation tentative.
During the installation tentative, the temporary files do not appare corrupt.
But there is something of strange.

The file `texlive.infra.tar.xz` is 214 kB and has the following sha1 hash:
`51d79be829834e3de3f0d9c1d36e892a0c05fe15 *texlive.infra.tar.xz`.

But the file `texlive.infra.tar` is 0 byte.

I suppose that the command used by the script to unpack it fail the operation.I tried to unpack the .xz file (copyied away to save it from the script's delete) with 7-zip and the .tar file was unpacked without problem. It is 980kB and the sha1 hash is:
`af815f498b3db43d614c44a606b123b82a30addf *texlive.infra.tar`

This tarball can be opened by 7-zip without error.

My opinion is that should be problems with the command used to unpack the .xz file.
How command use the script for this operation?

Thanks.

---

Update 2:

## SOLVED!!

Problems was caused by an older version of msys present in my path.
I'd removed it from the path temprary and the istallation works!

There are some components conflict with `xz` operations.

Comment: Have you tried using a different mirror (other than this italian one)?

Comment: @daleif yes, as reported in the answer I tried to use different mirrors.

Comment: Interesting, I just installed on a win10 laptop earlier today. You did do a proper unzip on the ZIP not just double click on the zip on run it from there? (the latter gives all sorts of problems)

Comment: @daleif No, I don't used any ZIP file. I istalled using the `install-tl-windows.exe` (tex live installer), with the option _Unpack Only_, an then ran the install-tl-windows.bat  file.

Comment: I always go the zip solution (it should not differ), but try downloading the zip from the website (install-tl.zip), unzip it and run `install-tl-windows.bat` from there. Additionally are you using some sort of synced drives? For example the Windows users where I work have their Desktop and Documents folders sync'ed with a file server. So I normally install from the Downloads folder as it specifically sits on the local drive)

Comment: @daleif Same issue using the installer from install-tl.zip. :-(. No synced drive in use.

Comment: Then it might be time to check your dist or ram. Here's something we could try. Try grappling this file (you can adapt the url to any mirror, this is just the one I use) http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/memoir.tar.xz, right click the downloaded file, windows should be able to do a sha1sum on that file. Post the sum and I'll do the same tomorrow on my work pc. It is if couse not foolproof, but if we hit it right we might not be able to get the same sum. Years ago I had a similar issue. Iso file kept having the wrong md5. Has a faulty ram

Comment: The reason for using memoir here us because that file hasn't changed since November. The tlpdb changes every day

Comment: If it might be memory, be extra careful with backups and so on, because it is easy to get file corruption. This is just a general comment and has nothing to do with your question specifically.

Comment: @daleif the computed sha1sum: 
`b19f466c3efd9ec3040ba1432f67ca9ba447ab84 *./memoir.tar.xz`

Comment: I get the same so it is not that. I think you made the right call to ask for help on the TL list.

Comment: @daleif thanks for all the support. I already ask to the TL list and I'm waiting for reply.
In the mean time I made some tests. Reported in the Main question.

Comment: I think you have had at least one answer from Norbert

Comment: For me, it is `git bash` path.